# ARM LPC2148 Bootloader filesystem problems

Tags: bootloader, windows, arm7

I installed Keil's LPC2148 [bootloader](https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/94) on my ARM board and as indicated in the docs my PC is able to identify it as a mass storage device. However, the bootloader uses FAT16 filesystem which is apparently incompatible with my Windows 7 Home Premium (64-bit) PC. It works just fine when operating on a Windows XP system and I am able to copy files to the ROM. 
As I didn't have XP mode on my Win7 machine, I loaded a virtual machine using VMWare with XP and bound the board's USB to it but to no avail. Any attempt to copy files into the device causes the virtual machine to 'hang'.

Why is it that the same copy-function works on a 'real' XP machine but not on a virtual machine? Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Try a different hypervisor. Maybe https://www.virtualbox.org/ works better. It is free for personal use and free for use at work when in *personally* install it on your PC. If your sysadmin at work installs it for you, you have to buy a license from Oracle.

Comment: What board are you using? Is the bootloader being installed on SD card?

Comment: I am using a version of Keil's LPC2148 BlueBoard that bought off a local supplier (the bootloader hex file was also supplied with the board). No, I flashed the ROM directly with the bootloader using NXP's FlashMagic.

Comment: @jippie: Nope, no use. I uninstalled VMware and tried VirtualBox which (with all its hassles of attaching a USB to the virtual machine) didn't make much difference. I am able to open the drive and I do see the image of the ROM as a .bin file as expected and I am able to delete the file just fine. I just am not able to copy to the drive. Could this be due to me having a 64-bit machine?

Comment: 64-bit guest or host OS?

Comment: The host is a 64-bit Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working now. It is a little weird that I needed to plug in a USB-Serial converter to the DB9 converter apart from the power USB. If anyone else has a similar problem, just plug in both the USB and the Serial cables in the ports and it should work.

Thanks to those who helped!